# How can I track a person and respond to their movement?

Tags: raspberry-pi, simulink, raspberry-pi2, raspberry-pi3

I was wondering if there was a way on a raspberry pi to track people, and then communicate with GPIO pins to turn servos so something faces their direction. I know it is possible to track using simulink, but I am not sure how to act on results. Thanks for any responses!

Comment: Use a camera and some software that identifies humans? Link the output of that to servo drivers. Go for it!

Comment: Thanks barny, that is exactly what I plan to do. However, I am a bit of a novice :) so I don't know how to go about it. Thanks for your response!